# inserting bulk data in mongo db, I get Error : "mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h:204"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

while inserting bulk data around million in mongo db, I get Error:

> WriteError({"code":8,"index":0,"errmsg":"assertion
>   C:\data\mci\src\src\mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h:204"

I am using NodeJS and Mongo DB.

Please let me know why it is coming I can share code also if needed

Comment: can you share code so that we can figure out

Comment: where do you get this error, in database server or in your application?

Answer (score -2):

For Bulk insertion : The size of the document must be less than or equal to the maximum `BSON` document size.

The maximum `BSON` document size is 16 megabytes.

We can check it on Mongo Shell by issuing following command

```
db.isMaster().maxBsonObjectSize/(1024*1024)
```